# Is it possible to get simultaneously suspended from all stack exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

I was having a bad day yesterday and wrote extremely provocative things on math overflow, math stack exchange, and philosophy stack exchange. I am worried that I could face a consequence. I have decided to stop writing inappropriate things. But just out of curiosity, is it possible to get simultaneously suspended from all stack exchange Q & A websites?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's called a network-wide suspension and it can only be applied by staff. It is used very sparingly for users who consistently cause problems on multiple sites. But also because once it's applied, it's rather difficult to remove the suspension. So we like to make sure that the user really *does* need that level of suspension, as they'll have to actually serve that full length. We generally wouldn't use this for someone who's never been suspended before unless they're obviously attempting to be a troll.

Comment: My account on math overflow has already been terminated.

Comment: I see you got suspended in *chat*, but nothing has happened with any of your on-site profiles... If you're suspended in chat, you're suspended from *all* chat rooms on chat.stackexchange.com, not just the ones associated with that site. That's just how chat suspensions work.

Comment: Oh, I couldn't access my account on mathoverflow yesterday. Maybe I was unsuspended.

Comment: @user107952 If you were suspended you'd have gotten a message informing you as to the reason for your suspension.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, network-wide suspensions are a thing, although it's reasonably rare for them to be necessary.